# how to change default path for Properties.Settings

Tags: .net, properties.settings

Whenever I do `Properties.Settings.Save()`, it commites the properties changes to `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` but I want the path to be `Application.CommonAppDataPath`.

where

```
Application.CommonAppDataPath = 
C:\Documents and Settings\**All Users**\Application Data\xxxxx\xxxx\1.0.0.0


Application.LocalUserAppDataPath =
C:\Documents and Settings\**gsankar**\Local Settings\Application Data\xxxxx\xxxx\1.0.0.0
```

Please let me know whether it's possible to change.  If so, please let me know how?

Answer (score 1):

use `Properties.Settings.Default.ParentPath = Application.CommonAppDataPath;` before calling `Properties.Settings.Save();`.