# Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); -> Where is that file

Tags: c#, .net, properties, settings, directory

I have app that uses Settings.
To save settings I use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To read tham I use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyCustomSetting;
```

In my folder with application I have only exe file.
No config files. My application works good, can read write settings.

Where is that file located if it is not in application folder?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481025/where-property-setting-value-stored-in-c-windows-application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On My Windows XP machine, the settings are saved in a file called user.config somewhere under either `C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Application Data\` or `C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Local Settings\Application Data\`

Update:

On Windows Vista and later, the locations have changed to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\` and `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\`

Answer (score 5):

This depends on what SettingsProvider you are using. By default, this is the [LocalFileSettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.localfilesettingsprovider.aspx)

Quoting from that page:

> Application-scoped settings and the default user-scoped settings are stored in a file named application.exe.config, which is created in the same directory as the executable file. Application configuration settings are read-only. Specific user data is stored in a file named user.config, stored under the user's home directory.

They may also go to the %APPDATA%

Answer (score 3):

you can get the path programmatically:

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath;
Textbox1 = path;
```

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows 7 machine, it's saved in:

Users\\AppData\Local\MyCompanyName\MyExeName\1.0.0.0\user.config

Replace MyCompanyName with something specific to you, and replace MyExeName with the name of your Exe. Mine is followed by a lot of random characters.

This threw me, too. I'm glad I'm not the only one. :) I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifiek path but i think it's in documents and settings
Place a breakpoint on the Save and the path should be visable in one of the members/submembers of Properties.Settings.Default

[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214131/how-to-change-default-path-for-properties-settings)