# App Config File not saving

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, app-config

I am using the below code lifted from MSDN, but its not updating my app.config file.
Am I missing something? Please help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.reliefPath = "reliefPath";
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I am targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: Forget about save option.

Comment: When referencing an external source (in this case MSDN) it would helpful if you linked to the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.config itself is never updated. Instead a copy is created in the isolated storage for your application. I believe it's under your profile's AppData\Roaming directory. That file is then loaded next time you run your application

Comment: Thank you so much! Found it in Application Data Folder.

Answer (score 0):

The settings may be saved in your App Data folder, in a user.config file:
[Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); -> Where is that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789252/properties-settings-default-save-where-is-that-file)