# C# App.config dont work on some systems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, app-config

In my program I save the font an some other data in the App.config file. But some users have problems with saving.

What could be a reason for that?

Example for saving:

```
PawnStar.Properties.Settings.Default.timerTime = (int)this.slTime.Value;
PawnStar.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: I've posted an example how I do save it. It works on some PCs but on some it dont

Comment: Does it fail silently to throw an exception?

Comment: Is the app installed in the place?  An the same computer can some users save and other users cannot?

Comment: If it dont work it is computerwide

Comment: Then is the app installed in the same place on where it works compared to where it does not.   And you should edit the question to some installs versus some users.

Comment: Yes, it's the same location

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050465/app-config-file-not-saving - without more info about 'have some problems' its hard to say.