# Does replacing a library (dll) file with a new version change Properties Settings?

Tags: c#, dll, properties, settings

I'm developnig a Windows Forms application.

I should upload new version of dll to users. If I do that, does it reset Properties.Settings to default values or will they stay saved (on user's computer)?

Comment: Which "Properties Settings"? (Also, the only way it could make a difference is if the settings were associated with or stored in the DLL.)

Comment: @user2864740 Properties of a library. The one that contains Resources and Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by uploading the DLL, you don't reset the settings 
Here you can get the answer -

[Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); -> Where is that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789252/properties-settings-default-save-where-is-that-file)

[Where are the Properties.Settings.Default stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-default-settings-stored)

Comment: Great, haven't found that. So these settings are saved in Windows' AppData folder and they can't be lost unless deleted. Thank you Rabi!