# C# Winform: Setting the file save location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, directory

My program must produce files from some given data. I'm dealing with PDFs and Excel documents. How do I allow the user to set the directory where the files will be saved? I'm not referring to `SaveFileDialog` where the user must choose the directory every time. 
I want the files to automatically be saved to the directory previously specified by the user. Something to this effect:

[image: YTD]

Most immediate solution I can think of is to store the directory in a file and read it every time a file is to be saved.

I also read about [Properties.Settings.Default.Save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789252/properties-settings-default-save-where-is-that-file), but is it relevant to my case?

Comment: Wasn't supposed to be my job. It was given to me.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Answer (score 2):

Use `FolderBrowserDialog` to get the folder...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Get the folder's path.

```
folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Then go into your project properties (Project menu > *Project Name* Properties), and click the settings tab. Add a new setting with a name of your choice, like `SaveLocation` with the type of `string`. Then you can save it like so...

```
Settings.Default["SaveLocation"] = folderName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And then, obviously, retrieve it like so...

```
string saveLocation = Settings.Default["SaveLocation"]
```

Read more about saving application settings here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You may care to use the registry to store information between sessions. This will require that you have admin privileges.  Since this is winform it may be.